# How do I add a host file to my program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Hi I would like to know if there is a way to add a standalone host file into my visual basic project that is only used by the program that I'm trying to make. I want to make a webbrowser that only shows YouTube.com. I already have the CefSharpBrowser installed and it is ready to visit websites.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. but you can implement a custom DNS though

Comment: Thanks for helping. Do you know how to do that? Im sadly not very good at this

Comment: its not gonna be simple for beginners. Can you describe in details what you are trying to accomplish? cuz chances are there is an easy way to do so

Comment: Okay. I want to have play YouTube videos without ads on this little program. So I think there are not many sites that need to be blocked becuase I told it to connect to youtube when the program starts

Comment: in this case I think you do need the custom dns. There are libraries out there which you can use though it will have some degree of learning curve

Comment: Okay thank you for helping. Could you help me find such libraries? as I have no clue what I should look out for

Comment: google c# custom dns and pick one you like

Comment: I googled it and I found this DNS library [link](https://github.com/kapetan/dns) I need to install this via NuGet. Should I look up what websites need to be blocked?

Comment: you can resolve only youtube's IP and mark all the rest as not found. Though im not sure if youtube will let you continue if you don't watch the ads.

Comment: Okay. Can you show me how to do that or should I look it up myself?

Comment: First you need to read up how DNS works. Once you know that it should be relatively easy to do since you are basically not resolving any other domains besides youtube.com.